# Take N Items from List on Condition

Tags: c#, list

I have the following:

```
IDictionary<QuestionDuration, Int32> rules = _service.GetRules(); 

List<Question> questions = _service.GetQuestions();

public class Question {
  public QuestionDuration Duration { get; set; }
}
```

The dictionary values (Int32) are the number of questions I need to take from the list with that specific duration ... So if I have the dictionary:

{ { QuestionDuration.M2, 5 }, { QuestionDuration.M4, 3 }, { QuestionDuration.M8, 0 }, ...

So I need to create a List from the original list with 5 questions of 2 minutes, 4 questions of 3 minutes, 0 questions of 8 minutes, etc ...

I was trying to group and use a lambda expression for this but I wasn't able ...

How can I do this?

Thank You,

Miguel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will create `IEnumerable<List<Question>>` (three lists for your dictionary of rules):

```
IDictionary<QuestionDuration, Int32> rules = _service.GetRules();
List<Question> questions = _service.GetQuestions();

var query = from r in rules
            select questions.Where(q => q.Duration == r.Key)
                            .Take(r.Value).ToList();
```

**Tip:** if you need to pick random questions in each list, then add `OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid())` just before `Take` operator. Or more random solution:

```
var rand = new Random();
var query = from r in rules
            select questions.Where(q => q.Duration == r.Key)
                            .OrderBy(q => rand.Next())
                            .Take(r.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: @lazyberszovsky: Elegant; but deterministic. I infer from context that the OP doesn't want the same questions in each category being selected every time.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens but questions shouldn't be same, because duration is different (if I understood question correctly)

Comment: @layberezovsky: But the first 2 minute question will be the same every time; same for each other duration. Do you have an equally elegant Shuffle up your sleeve by any chance?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you could add `.SelectMulti(q => q)` to flatten it out and give a `List<Question>`, then shuffle those to randomize the order of the resultset.  Fun :P

Comment: @Corey I think you meant `SelectMany` :) Yes, it is option, but I thought OP wants separate lists

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yeah, that's the bunny.  It's early here :P